# Права на создание папки по пути /opy/lampp/htdocs/myApp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, phpstorm

У меня трабл с правами в убунту.

Создаю папку в папке с приложением (тут и возникает ошибка в доступе).
[image: Вывод ошибки во фронте]
Использую apache (lampp, путь /opt/lampp/htdocs/app)

Пользуюсь phpStorm.

Права задал такие: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
$copy_to = dirname('/opt/lampp/htdocs/generate_theme_wp/downloads/');    
if( !file_exists($copy_to) ) {
        if (mkdir($copy_to, 0755, true)) {
              echo "Папка уже создана <br>";
        } else {
              echo 'Папка создаётся<br>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: а права на каталог controllers какие установлены?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте рекурсивно задать права на запись:

```
chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/generate_theme_wp/
```

если ваш пользователь не имеет прав на /opt то добавьте еще `sudo` в начало.

Также было бы не лишним глянуть где ваше приложение пытается создать директорию.

Comment: Пробовал не помогло. Возможно проблема в том, что запускаю ide phpstorm от другого пользователя (который зарегестрирован на него) и нужно его добавить в группу root. Подскажете как узнать от какого пользователя открывается ide и задать ему рут права?